# How can I pull a specific row of data from CSV using Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv that looks like the following and trying to have it return only a specific row based on a specific input.

```
"id", "name",
"1", "bp",
"2", "ah",
"3", "sh"
```

Is it possible to do something like this where it only returns the row if id is `== 2`? So the returned value will just be `{'id': '2', 'name': 'ah'}`

```
new_dict = []
with open(file_data, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if (row['support_id']) == 2:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can directly retrieve a row in a CSV file based on an id value, without first reading the rows previous to that row?

Comment: First issue: You 'new_dict' is a list. A new dict would be `new_dict = {}`. What seems to wrong with what you are doing otherwise however?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Yes, I was seeing if it is possible to just retrieve a row in csv by just providing an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
% cat /tmp/file.csv
"id", "name",
"1", "bp",
"2", "ah",
"3", "sh,
"2", "second 2",
```

(ie, I added one addition line with `"2"` as the `"id"` filed)

You can use the csv reader (rather than the DictReader) to do this:

```
import csv

with open(fn) as f_in:
    row_with_2=[row for row in csv.reader(f_in) if row[0]=='2'] 

>>> row_with_2
[['2', ' "ah"', ''], ['2', ' "second 2"', '']]
```

If you want to know which line of the file the `'2'` id occurs, you can add `enumerate`:

```
with open(fn) as f_in:
    row_with_2=[(i, row) for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f_in)) if row[0]=='2']
# [(1, ['2', ' "ah"', '']), (3, ['2', ' "second 2"', ''])]
```

If you want to keep the header as a separate data element:

```
with open(fn) as f_in:
    header=next(f_in)
    row_with_2=[(i, row) for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f_in)) if row[0]=='2']
```

You can also use `DictReader` this way:

```
with open(fn) as f_in:
    reader=csv.DictReader(f_in)
    data=[di for di in reader if di['id']=='2']
#data=[{'id': '2', ' "name"': ' "ah"', '': ''}, {'id': '2', ' "name"': ' "second 2"', '': ''}]
```